# Why is the order of initialization of object streams important in java network programming?

Tags: java, serialization, network-programming

Based on the following information from my prof:

---

The client creates `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` objects to send the request, and to receive the reply. The `CalculateClient` constructor is:

```
public CalculateClient( String host, int port )
    throws IOException
{
    /* determine the address of the server and connect to it */
    serverHost = InetAddress.getByName( host );
    serverPort = port;
    calculate = new Socket( serverHost, serverPort );

    OutputStream out = calculate.getOutputStream();
    request = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream( out ));
    request.flush();

    // ObjectInputStream blocks until
    // the connected side flushes its ObjectOutputStream
    InputStream in = calculate.getInputStream();
    reply = new ObjectInputStream( in );
}
```

In network applications, the construction order of the input and output socket streams when using object streams is important. The `ObjectOutputStream` must be created first. It then should be flushed. The `ObjectInputStream` can then be created.

---

He doesn't elaborate as to why. Why is this true?

Comment: Read the following javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is explained in the comments of the code you posted, isn't it?

> // ObjectInputStream blocks until
>   // the connected side flushes its ObjectOutputStream

So if you try to create the `ObjectInputStream` the constructor waits until the corresponding `ObjectOutputStream`'s `flush()` method is called. Since you haven't created it yet, guess what happens?

As an alternative to asking this question, you could have simply switched the creation order and observed the results. It takes arguably less effort on your part and as a bonus you've learned how to problem-solve and think critically.